# How can I send an email in the background of an App in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'm making an app using Android Studio and I need it to send an email in the background, without the user knowing. I've tried Async methods but I don't know how to get them to work. Anyone any tutorials or help?

Comment: May I ask what kind of emails you want to send without the user noticing?

Comment: Its a security app, so the idea is when the alarm is activated an email is sent to the user's email address informing them of the event. I've had no success following examples. Any help much appreciated!